# What is the difference between an .appxupload and an .appxbundle and which one should I upload to the store?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have just build my application for `UWP` for the Windows store.

Visual Studio had produced a collection of files. Some of which are:

```
MyApp.appxupload
MyApp.appxBundle
```

What is the difference between these two files? and which one should I upload to the store?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/upload-app-packages) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps)?

Comment: So you asked a question, then went on to answer it, and now you need what exactly?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not sure how I answered it. What is the difference...?

Comment: @AVK no I didn't see those, but they look useful. I will read them now

Comment: You have two options, and concluded, that one isn't. That leaves you with one option. What else do you need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the difference between these two files? and which one should I upload to the store?

Both of them can be uploaded to the Store, which is up to your need. See the **Package** section of submission in Dashboard:

[image]

`.xap` can be Windows Phone 8/8.1 Silverlight package format.

`.appx` can also be accepted by Dev Center, but for Windows universal app, it won't collect crash analytics experience from Dev Center if you do not include pdb symbol files. The `.appxupload` file is created as part of the Visual Studio packaging process and contains two other files: `.appx` and `.appxsym`. The `.appxsym` file is a compressed .pdb file containing public symbols of your app used for crash analytics in the Windows Dev Center. That's why we should upload `.appxupload` file for Store submission.

The `.appxbundle` file can reduce the size of the app that users download, which is very meaningful to the package containing language-specific assets, varying image-scale assets, or resources that apply to specific versions of Microsoft DirectX. Users just need to download the part of your package resource that works on their device.

Besides, with `appxbundle`, you can directly generate a package for x86, x64 and arm architecture so you don't need to create them one by one. Please note that once you upload `.appxbundle` as your Store package you're not able to go back to non-appxbundle in your future submission.

For more details, please read related article in [Packaging apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/).

Comment: appxupload file is smaller than appxbundle for me. how is that can reduce size of the app that user downloads? both files include all architectures in my case.

Answer (score 3):

From this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps it states:

> To sell your Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app or distribute it to
>   other users, you need to create an appxupload package for it. When you
>   create the appxupload, another appx package will be generated to use
>   for testing and sideloading. You can distribute your app directly by
>   sideloading the appx package to a device. This article describes the
>   process of configuring, creating and testing a UWP app package. For
>   more information about sideloading, see Sideload Apps in Windows 10.

also on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/upload-app-packages it states:

> **Important For Windows 10**, you should always upload the .appxupload
>   file here, not the .appx or .appxbundle. For more info about packaging
>   UWP apps for the Store, see Packaging Universal Windows apps for
>   Windows 10.

So in conclusion the `appxupload` is for uploading to the Windows store and the `appxbundle` is for sideloading

Comment: When I try to upload appxupload file I am getting a weird JS error. The uploading bar continues to upload (shows in progress) for ever. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675388/uwp-app-uploading-fails-microsoft-store. Even the old appxupload files that were uploaded and release succesfully are throwing the same error.