# UWP app uploading fails Microsoft store

Tags: c#, uwp, store

I am trying to upload a `UWP` app to the windows store. The progress bar keeps on showing and I get the following *error* in the dev console.

```
File.lastModifiedDate is deprecated. Use File.lastModified instead.  AppSubmissionPackages.app.js:23:16
Setting state: 0  XfusUploader_V3.js:591:13
message Setting state: 0 level 1  XfusFileUploader.js:206:25
Upload Initialized  XfusUploader_V3.js:591:13
message Upload Initialized level 1  XfusFileUploader.js:206:25
Setting metadata for AssetId: 5e0205e4-03c4-47d8-9914-56daa3a9bf01  XfusUploader_V3.js:591:13
message Setting metadata for AssetId: 5e0205e4-03c4-47d8-9914-56daa3a9bf01 level 1  XfusFileUploader.js:206:25
File name: SLNX_1.0.34.0_x86_x64_arm_bundle.appxupload  XfusUploader_V3.js:591:13
message File name: SLNX_1.0.34.0_x86_x64_arm_bundle.appxupload level 1  XfusFileUploader.js:206:25
File size: 49399189  XfusUploader_V3.js:591:13
message File size: 49399189 level 1  XfusFileUploader.js:206:25
CorrelationId: 5e0205e4-03c4-47d8-9914-56daa3a9bf01  XfusUploader_V3.js:591:13
message CorrelationId: 5e0205e4-03c4-47d8-9914-56daa3a9bf01 level 1  XfusFileUploader.js:206:25
message Setting asset metadata on server level 0  XfusFileUploader.js:206:25
Set metadata failed: AssetId: 5e0205e4-03c4-47d8-9914-56daa3a9bf01 StatusCode: 0  XfusUploader_V3.js:591:13
message Set metadata failed: AssetId: 5e0205e4-03c4-47d8-9914-56daa3a9bf01 StatusCode: 0 level 1  XfusFileUploader.js:206:25
Setting state: 500  XfusUploader_V3.js:591:13
message Setting state: 500 level 1  XfusFileUploader.js:206:25
message The asset cannot be uploaded. Try creating a new one level 2
```

using **FireFox** browser. Even with **Chrome** I am getting a similar error.

Comment: According to the error info, your asset can be invalid so you might re-create a new package and try it again. You can refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets#asset-types) to get more details about asset types, their uses, and recommended file names.

Comment: Even the appx files that were uploaded, released to the market previously. They are throwing the similar error.

Comment: Files worked before don't necessarily work now. Open your app manifest and check if there's any errors in it. Also update your nuget packages to the latest, update your VS to the latest and see if that would make a difference.

Comment: App manifest doesn't have any issues. Updated all the packages. Even install VS 2017. Still getting the same error.

Comment: + I cannot pause or cancel the upload. If I try to cancel, it says no file being uploaded in the dev console.

Comment: I think their uploading is broken.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project n submitting it? Would that still fail?

Comment: @cykopath, I had a nearly identical problem that was driving me crazy.  It turned out to be the speed of the upload for me.  My home ADSL took about 30 minutes to upload, after which the UI just said "Error" with no code and Resume and Cancel buttons didn't work.  When I loaded from work (< 1 minute), it worked fine.  Too many factors to say if this addresses your problem.

Comment: My internet speed is not slow. Its pretty fast. @Adrian.

Comment: @JustinXL I tried uploading old appxbundle files that were uploaded and released successfully before. Even they are throwing the same error.

Comment: No, don't try your old package, I told you to try a new and empty one.

Comment: repairing Visual studio. After this will create an empty one. Will update in a  little while. Thanks @JustinXL

Comment: Might be because the project still has a reference to the said asset but the actual file was deleted

Comment: I am getting the same error even if I create a new app and associate it with the windows store app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a firewall that was blocking access to upload.xbox..... domain name.
I don't know why Firefox was not showing Ajax request failing.